# Is there any difference between "getting" and "to be getting"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between "getting" and "to be getting"?

Example "Trees getting cut down." and "Trees are getting cut down."

Is there any difference between these 2 sentences ?

Comment: Only the second is an actual "sentence", an independent clause; it has a finite verb (*are*)  and can stand on its own. The first is merely a phrase or a subordinate clause which can act as a nominal.

Comment: The second could stand alone in "headlinese": for example, as a caption to a photo.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a difference.

*Trees are getting cut down* refers to an action that is in progress.  Someone is cutting the trees.  It is the form encountered more frequently.

*Trees getting cut down* can be used in the context of an intended action.  To explain:  If someone has decided to cut some trees down, they may be referred to as the *trees getting cut down*.  The trees are still standing at the time of speaking.  To put it another way, you would say "*These are the trees getting cut down, those are the trees being left to grow.*".

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge, we can't write (v+ing) without (verb to be) before it.

Comment: Looks like you don’t know gerund…